# How do I configure jsc.parser.usingDecl in vite build?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, vite, browser-extension

I followed the [Vite Plugin Web Extension](https://vite-plugin-web-extension.aklinker1.io/guide/) tutorial to build cross-browser extensions.

I'm using `typescript` `5.3.2` and my code makes use of the `using` [keyword](https://www.totaltypescript.com/typescript-5-2-new-keyword-using) to automatically call `dispose`.

When I try to run `vite build`, I get:

```
Using declaration is not enabled. Set jsc.parser.usingDecl to true (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
file: C:/Users/xxxxx/source/repos/.../types.ts:73:14
71:
72:         //NOTE: learn more about 'using' keyword: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescri...
73:         using awaiter = new RequestMonitor();
```

Here's my `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import webExtension, { readJsonFile } from "vite-plugin-web-extension";

const target = process.env.TARGET || "chrome";

function generateManifest() {
  const manifest = readJsonFile(`src/manifest.${target}.json`);
  const pkg = readJsonFile("package.json");
  return {
    name: `${pkg.name} (${target})`,
    description: `${pkg.description} for ${target}`,
    version: pkg.version,
    ...manifest,
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  define:{
    __BROWSER__: JSON.stringify(target)
  },
  publicDir: "assets",
  build: {
    outDir: "build"
  },
  plugins: [
    webExtension({
      manifest: generateManifest,
      watchFilePaths: ["package.json", "manifest.json"],
      browser: target,
    }),
  ],
});
```

How do I set the `jsc.parser.usingDecl` to *true*?